# SFTP How to List Large # of Files

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko, rclone

I am currently working on SFTP load to GCS bucket. However, I am able to do it for a limited number of files in any given SFTP directory by getting the list of files & iterating the absolute path of files. However, if the directory has too many files (or files within another folder), I am not able to do a simple ls & get the list of files to download from SFTP. Following is the working code to get the list of files in any given directory recursively from sftp:

```
import sys
from stat import S_ISDIR, S_ISREG
import paramiko


sftp_url = '<URL>'
sftp_user = '<USER>'
sftp_pwd = '<PWD>'


def get_sftp_obj(sftp_cred_dict):
     server = sftp_cred_dict['server']
     username = sftp_cred_dict['username']
     password = sftp_cred_dict['password']
     timeout_min = sftp_cred_dict['timeout_min']
     paramiko.sftp_file.SFTPFile.MAX_REQUEST_SIZE = pow(2, 22) #4MB Chunk Default
     transport = paramiko.Transport((server, 22))
     transport.connect(username=username, password=password)
     sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
     sftp.get_channel().settimeout(timeout_min*60)
     return sftp


 def sftp_get_recursive_files(path, skip_dir_list, sftp, sftp_files=[]):
     item_list = sftp.listdir_attr(path)
     for item in item_list:
         mode = item.st_mode
         item = item.filename
         if S_ISDIR(mode):
             path_build = path + '/' + item
             if not(item in skip_dir_list):
                 sftp_get_recursive_files(path_build, skip_dir_list, sftp, sftp_files)
             else:
                 print('skip directory files: ' + path_build)
         elif S_ISREG(mode):
             sftp_file_path = path + '/' + item
             sftp_files.append(sftp_file_path)
     return sftp_files


 def main():
     sftp_cred_dict = {
         "server": sftp_url,
         "username": sftp_user,
         "password": sftp_pwd,
         "timeout_min": 60
     }
     skip_dir_list = ["archive"]
     arguments = sys.argv
     ls_dir = arguments[1]
     print(ls_dir)
     sftp = get_sftp_obj(sftp_cred_dict)
     files = sftp_get_recursive_files(ls_dir, skip_dir_list, sftp, [])
     print(len(files))


if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

I get the following exception after some time of execution:

```
(venv-sftp) user@poc-sftp:~/experiments/sftp-v1$ python ls-sftp.py /BU/SYSTEM/outbound/SYSTEM_Txn_Payment

  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/experiments/sftp-v1/venv-sftp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 852, in _read_response
    t, data = self._read_packet()
  File "/home/user/experiments/sftp-v1/venv-sftp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp.py", line 201, in _read_packet
    x = self._read_all(4)
  File "/home/user/experiments/sftp-v1/venv-sftp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp.py", line 188, in _read_all
    raise EOFError()
EOFError


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ls-sftp.py", line 62, in <module>
    main()
  File "ls-sftp.py", line 57, in main
    files = sftp_get_recursive_files(ls_dir, skip_dir_list, sftp, [])
  File "ls-sftp.py", line 27, in sftp_get_recursive_files
    item_list = sftp.listdir_attr(path)
  File "/home/user/experiments/sftp-v1/venv-sftp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 246, in listdir_attr
    t, msg = self._request(CMD_READDIR, handle)
  File "/home/user/experiments/sftp-v1/venv-sftp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 822, in _request
    return self._read_response(num)
  File "/home/user/experiments/sftp-v1/venv-sftp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 854, in _read_response
    raise SSHException("Server connection dropped: {}".format(e))
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Server connection dropped:
```

[Update 1]

I tried to use the following code using find command I get `paramiko.SSHException: Channel closed.`

```
def sftp_get_all_files(path, sftp_cred_dict):
    command = "cd " + path + '; find . ! -path archive'
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(sftp_cred_dict['server'], username=sftp_cred_dict['username'], password=sftp_cred_dict['password'], port=22)
    (stdin, stdout, stderr) = ssh.exec_command(command)
    all_files = stdout.readlines()
    return all_files
```

[Update-2]
I tried to configure the sftp connection using rclone

```
sftp-v1$rclone ls -vv --dump headers --exclude=/archive/** dpprdsftp:/BU/SYSTEM/outbound/SYSTEM_Txn_Payment
DEBUG : rclone: Version "v1.57.0" starting with parameters ["rclone" "ls" "-vv" "--dump" "headers" "--exclude=/archive/**" "dpprdsftp:/BU/SYSTEM/outbound/SYSTEM_Txn_Payment"]
DEBUG : Creating backend with remote "dpprdsftp:/BU/SYSTEM/outbound/SYSTEM_Txn_Payment"
DEBUG : Using config file from "/home/user/.config/rclone/rclone.conf"
DEBUG : sftp://dpprdsftp@xx.xxx.xx.xx:22//BU/SYSTEM/outbound/SYSTEM_Txn_Payment: New connection xx.xxx.x.x:xxxxx->yy.yyy.y.yy:22 to "SSH-2.0-CrushFTPSSHD"
DEBUG : sftp://dpprdsftp@xx.xxx.xx.xx:22//BU/SYSTEM/outbound/SYSTEM_Txn_Payment: Connection failed, closing: connection lost
ERROR : : error listing: error listing "": connection lost
DEBUG : 2 go routines active
Failed to ls with 2 errors: last error was: error listing "": connection lost
```

Do I need to ask the sftp admin to enable something from the source?

Comment: Can you download the files using any commandline/GUI SFTP client?

Comment: For the directory with less number of files - yes! 
For the directory with a large number of files - no not really, as the files contain timestamps in the name -- so it would not be possible to predict the file names. Is there any way to use wildcard?

Comment: If you cannot do it in SFTP client, you won't be able to code it either. But that information should have been in your question from the very beginning! Have the server fixed. Or use the workaround suggested by @Iñigo (if you have a shell access at all – we do not know that either).

Comment: not sure but i've updated the question after seeing your question already -- betw is it the limitations of sftp? I cannot find a lot of documentation on this > is this something related to this? https://superuser.com/questions/630175/why-is-ssh-sftp-failing-for-commands-with-larger-returns

Comment: No it's not limitation of SFTP in general. It seems to be a limitation or rather a bug of your particular SFTP server. Or some networking issue. Though you were not very specific about the exact problem you face in SFTP client, so we can only guess.

Comment: I understand, let me connect with the source. I tried using rclone > same issue though (again, it works for limited files in the directory) 
`ERROR : : error listing: error listing "": connection lost`

Comment: In any case you do not have a programming problem so far. Either get the underlying non-programming issue fixed or if you want to ask here, ask about possible programming workarounds. Your current question is off-topic.

Comment: is there any programmatic way of setting (or enforcing any particular setting) from sftp client (paramiko in this case)?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. What setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a filelist quickly using the [find(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) executing the find command in ssh:

```sh
ssh user@host "cd /some/where/in/the/filesystem ; find ."
```

You can skip directories with `find` using `! -path skip_this_dir ! -path skip_this_dir_too`. This example skips everything that has "archive" on its path:

```sh
ssh user@host "cd /some/where/in/the/filesystem ; find . ! -path archive "
```

You can do it with paramiko:

```py
import paramiko

command = "cd somewhere; find . ! -path archive"
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("host", "port", "username", "password")
_, stdout, _= ssh.exec_command(command)

all_files= stdout.readlines()
```

Comment: I think this is the only way via SSH due to sftp limitations -- i.e: get the list of files (in the above case it was 200K+ files on one directory) & so iterating the file names & execute functions can be the only option and it's pretty much a one-time thingy > thanks for the heads-up. (to the one who downvoted this problem -- it is still a programmatic challenge on SFTP if it's not under the developer radar)